# MySQL Fulltext matches everything but the exact match?

Tags: php, mysql, full-text-search, match

I am facing a weird situation where my full text search query seems to match everything except the exact match...

I mean if the input is:

> Empire Total War

it will match it as:

> Empire Total War Limited Edition
>   ...altough there is a record in the database that says exactely: **Empire Total War**

This is my query:

```
     $query_GID = "SELECT game, gameID, 
    MATCH (game) AGAINST ('$game_title') AS score 
FROM gkn_catalog_match WHERE MATCH (game) AGAINST
  ('$game_title');";
$result_GID = $dbc->query($query_GID);
$row_GID = mysqli_fetch_array($result_GID,MYSQLI_ASSOC);
```

For debugging purposes I went ahead and wrote this code to output all the matching alternatives in the returned array, however the exact match is not within it...

```
$GID = $row_GID['gameID'];
$GName = $row_GID['game'];
$Gscore = $row_GID['score'];
$max_score = 0;
$data = array();
while($row_GID = mysqli_fetch_assoc($result_GID)) {
if($row_GID['score'] > $max_score){ $max_score = $row_GID['score']; } //because we are ordering by score we can assume on the first run this wil be the max score.
echo "<br><b>Alternatives: " .$row_GID['game']."".@number_format(($row_GID['score']/$max_score)*100,0)."%</b>\n";

}
```

My question is: Why am I not getting the desired/exact match even though the input string AND the record in my database are identical? 
And even if I output the array it seems like the exact match is not even pulled from the database as its nowhere to be found in the array.

Edit:

Example Situation
Records in Database:

> Crysis
>  Crysis 2
>  Crysis 2 Maximum Edition
>  Crysis 3
>  Crysis 3 Hunter
>   Edition
>
> Search String (Input): Crysis 3 
> Match returned by query: Crysis 3
>   Hunter Edition

Crysis 3 is not being matched instead another record like Crysis 3 Hunter Edition is matched, which is... unexpected as I want it to match Crysis 3.

When I output the $row array of this query I can see that Crysis 3 is not included:
Alternatives: Crysis 3 Hunter Edition 100%
Alternatives: Crysis 2 Maximum Edition 82%
Alternatives: Crysis 70%
Alternatives: Far Cry 3 Deluxe Edition 32%
Alternatives: Far Cry 2 Fortune Edition 32%
Alternatives: SimCity 4 Deluxe Edition 31%
Alternatives: SimCity Limited Edition 31%
Alternatives: Battlefield 3 Premium Edition 31%
Alternatives: Battlefield 3 Limited Edition 31%
Alternatives: Civilization 5 Gold Edition 31%

Edit 2:

Entering the query manually returns the desired result. 
So the query seems to work, however I seem to lost the first entry of the returned array...

Comment: Change your `do` - `while` to just a `while`.  I suspect that the first record returned is the one you are looking for, but it may not show up.

Comment: what happens when you run the query manually?

Comment: If I enter my query manually I am getting the desired/exact match. @SableFoste I changed the do - while to a while but still the exact match is not showing up. The only way to make it show up is to enter the query manually...

Comment: **Please *please please*** use prepared queries...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I solved my problem by moving the array allocation `outside` of the `while` loop. 
Now the Fulltext query matches the game titles up to 99.9% if they exist within the database.

If not, it goes kinda crazy.